# PHP alternative to xdiff

Tags: php, windows-10

I have WAMP with php 7 installed and get a fatal error to an undefined function when trying to use xdiff_file_diff(). PECL and HTTP aren't listed in the php extensions on WAMP to be activated. The website for the PECL package doesn't clarify what the difference between "thread safe" or "non-thread safe" means for the .dll file...

I modified the original bootstrap file and want to compare the modified to the original and output the changes to another file. I feel like I could do it manually in the time it will take me to figure out how to make xdiff work... is there a less direct approach I can take with fread() to compare the two files and output only the changes? Can this be done with the command prompt on Windows (obviously not using fread but some alternative maybe)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use a windows [diff tool](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en), get a decent IDE that offers local history, use some sort of version control (SVN/Git).

Comment: Great link! Thanks a lot.